# Web API - JWT - Default user for anonymous access

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I'm setting up a site using Web API and JSON Web Tokens.  However, a portion of the site is open for anonymous access so end-users can submit information for a variety of questions/answers.  Everything is working fine, but I'd like to prevent a malicious user from possibly tampering with another's ongoing submission.

Would supplying each anonymous user with a "default" user that has a random hash value in the claim collection help prevent this?  The hash could then be compared with any request that comes in by using it as part of the query criteria when interacting with the database.

```
public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user;
        if ((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.UserName) || context.UserName.ToLower() == "undefined") 
            && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.Password) || context.Password.ToLower() == "undefined"))
        {
            user = await userManager.FindAsync(@"guest", @"somePassword");
        }
        else
        {
            user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        }

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        var oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT");
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);            
        context.Validated(ticket);
    }
}
```

Set the ClaimTypes.Hash value in the anonymous user's claim collection to be passed with each subsequent request.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);

        if (!userIdentity.HasClaim(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Hash))
        {
            var bytes = new byte[16];
            using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(bytes);
                userIdentity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Hash, BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower()));
            }
        }

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Are there any issues with this approach and/or better alternatives?

Comment: How would a malicious user tamper with an ongoing submission?

Comment: Since each user would be using the same "guest" account, all each would need to do is alter the ID in the request URL and/or payload and they could potentially send a POST for another submission.  I had originally thought to use GUID for the submission ID's to minimize this risk, but currently am using integers.